# Can you share WebAssembly memory between Web Workers?

Tags: javascript, shared-memory, web-worker, webassembly

Is it possible to share WebAssembly.memory between 2 workers by using postMessage, something like SharedArrayBuffer? And if the answer is yes, how?

Answer (score 9):

You can create a WebAssembly shared memory instance via the JavaScript API:

```
const memory = new WebAssembly.Memory({
  initial: 80,
  maximum: 80,
  shared: true
});
```

You can then send this memory instance to a Web Worker via `postMessage`:

```
const worker = new Worker("worker.js");
worker.postMessage({ memory });
```

The file `worker.js` can then create a WebAssembly module using this shared memory instance, allowing it to be shared across module instance in different threads.

For a more complete example, see this blog post:

[Faster Fractals with Multi-Threaded WebAssembly](https://blog.scottlogic.com/2019/07/15/multithreaded-webassembly.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have written your posts several times and I was interested to talk you about them. In the worker.js can I use some instructions like what we use for SharedArrayBuffer in JS? And I will be grateful if you introduce me a link to talk you.

Comment: I want to increment the content of memory from 0 in a infinite loop and read its value in the code whenever I want. And my question is: how to implement this part of code in the worker and how to read it? Thanks.